# Is there a way to convert all jsp files to static pages at once on server?

Tags: java, jsp, service-worker

I have a website and now I want it to be able to work offline. I'm trying using service-worker to implement this function, but unfortunately, my website is written in multiple .jsp files. So when one jsp jumps to another jsp, the internet is required, as jsp is not able to be resolved in client browsers. Is there a way to solve this problem? Or do I need to rewrite all the jsp to one file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Impossible to answer without more details. How much of the content is dynamically generated (for example from database entries)? And how about interactive functionality (forms, searches, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

If your site is running on your own computer, configure it to accept requests on 127.0.0.1.  Then you can use it when you are disconnected from the internet.

If the problem is that your JSPs link to each other via absolute URLs using your server's DNS name you could:

- change the JSPs to use relative URLs, or
- (hack!) temporarily tweak your DNS resolver to resolve the server DNS name to 127.0.0.1.

In general, it is not possible to convert a JSP to a static page, and still have it work properly.